# Can we follow redirects with Typheous Ruby?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, redirect

Is it possible to follow redirects with Typhoeus and how?

Answer (score 6):

Just write something like this:

```
res = Typhoeus::Request.get(url, {:follow_location => true})
```

Comment: It's now `:followlocation => true`.

Comment: Thanks for the fix. Could even be `followlocation: true` with the new syntax.

Answer (score 2):

In the latest version of Typhoeus (0.5.0) this has been changed to "followlocation: true". - https://github.com/typhoeus/typhoeus